# Python: How to assign a value as an actual parameter when not using numbers?

Tags: python, function, parameters

I'm sorry if this is a really stupid question; I'm an English major taking a COSC class for an elective (stupid decision, I know) and so none of this comes easily to me.

**This is the problem I'm trying to solve:**

Write a program that takes in a file that has a message. The message can be any length.

Your program will contain two functions. The first should have a function that processes the contents of the file. The second will take the output from the first function and will print the message in a box of asterisks.

The input file should just be a single-lined message (see attached input example). The output should take that message, split it between two lines, and center it in the box (see attached output example).

**This is the code I currently have:**

```
    def func1(process_contents): 
       infile=open("october.txt", "r")
       process_contents=print(infile.read())
       return process_contents

    def func2():
       outfile=open("october_output.txt", "w")
       print(func1(message), file=outfile)
       outfile.close()
```

(I have not yet attempted to create the box of asterisks...I am simply trying to get the functions to work first). I understand that I cannot assign another variable (i.e. "message") to the formal parameter "process_contents" in func1, that I need to assign a VALUE as the acutal parameters...but as I'm not using numbers in this problem, what is the value I'm using??

*Thank you so so much!!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't necessarily need a formal parameter in `func1()`.

```
def func1():
    infile = open("october.txt", "r")
    process_contents = infile.read()
    return process_contents

def func2():
        message = func1()
        print("asterisks" + message + "box thingy")
```

Although, you can use the formal parameter to generalize the function like this:

```
FILENAME = "october.txt" # or rather something like sys.argv[1]

def func1(FILENAME):
    infile = open(FILENAME, "r")
    process_contents = infile.read()
    return process_contents

def func2():
    message = func1(FILENAME)
    print("asterisks" + message + "box thingy")
```

Answer (score 1):

The `print` function writes by default to `stdout`, but does not return a value. Hence, you have to replace `process_contents=print(infile.read())` with `process_contents=infile.read()`. This will assign the value returned by `infile.read()` to the `process_contents` variable.

Further, I would recommend to use the [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) statement for opening a file, like it is also used by [the example](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html?highlight=open#open) given by the python manual.

Comment: Thank you!!! - I changed the code to read process_contents=infile.read(). But when I put func2() at the end of my code, with the idea of running through both functions, I am told "message" (used in func2) is not defined. I want "message" to be the actual parameter assigned to func1's formal parameter "process_contents,"....but how do I define "message" in func2??

Comment: Nevermind nevermind I got it to work!!!!! I just got rid of "message" and didn't give any parameters to func1. Thank you for your help!!!!!!!

Comment: You are very welcome. Since it seemed to me you are following a Python-Beginners-Tutorial with some exercises, I intentionally did not provide a full solution to the task, but only answered your concrete questions and gave some hints. Otherwise I felt I would have scammed you out of many Eureka!-moments and a lot of fun while discovering Python by yourself. Note that the answer by @tanmay-agrawal also does (probably intentionally) not contain code an experienced Python programmer would write.